# Amazon SES / Rails : 553 Invalid Email Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, amazon-ses

I am trying to send emails from my rails 2.5 app through Amazon SES.  For some reason, it won't accept my emails when the FROM address has a name I.E.

```
"Chuck Norris" <chuck@norris.com>
```

If I send the FROM email address as just chuck@norris.com, then it sends along just fine, so I know that the action mailer config is right.

I read the docs and still have no ideas about why it's failing.  The address seems to be formatted correctly, and sends just fine through any other SMTP relay.

When I write the email address to the log file I see this:

```
"Saint Leo Admissions" <admissions@saintleo.edu>
```

Which looks good to me.  But when I try to send the email, Amazon responds with this error message:

```
553 <Saint Leo Admissions <admissions@saintleo.edu> Invalid email address.
```

As you can see, the email address looks different when I dump it than it does in the error message.  I've been stuck on this for a couple days.  I even tried using a gem that is supposed to correctly format email addresses and had the same problem.  I also tried single quotes around the vanity name and that gives me the same error.  If I try to remove the <> then i get this error `501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided`

I'm stuck.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are you constructing the name + address string?  Can you show that code?

Comment: `@from = "\"#{recommendation.organization.settings[:outbound_emails][:from_vanity]}\" <#{recommendation.organization.settings[:outbound_emails][:from_address]}>"`

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this issue while using the [mail](https://rubygems.org/gems/mail/) gem in Rails.

I checked and confirmed that the email domain that I was using was verified in Amazon SES.

The issue was that there was a comma in my email address sender.

**Here's how I solved it:**

The previous email was

```
Clarence Dickson, DL <support@dickson.com>"
```

I simply removed the comma after Clarence Dickson

```
 Clarence Dickson DL <support@dickson.com>"
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**